# Invalid Object name 'Subject_Marks'

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Subject_Marks
(   
    Marks_ID int primary key,
    Maths_Score int,
    Science_Score int,
    Social_Score int,
    English_Score int,
    SUPW_Score int,
    Student_ID int  not null

    );

INSERT into Subject_Marks VALUES
(1,1001, 50, 99,98,45,57);
```

NOT ABLE TO JOIN THIS TABLE WITH OTHER TABLE SHOWN BELOW.

```
CREATE TABLE Student_Data
(   
    Student_ID int IDENTITY(1001,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Student_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Student_Address VARCHAR(100),
    Student_Phone bigint,
    Student_Email VARCHAR(30),
    college_id int NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: SQL is a query language.  What is your DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Since Student_ID is the key providing the relationship, you need to use this in a join. So, you need to construct a join like below for SQL Server:

```
select sd.* , sm.*
from Student_Data sd
inner join Subject_Marks sm on sm.Student_ID = sd.Student_ID
```